# Why is bool([]) == False while [] == False is False and not True in python boolean logic

Tags: python, boolean, logic, boolean-logic, boolean-expression

I've just started learning Python and i was trying this

```
[] == False #False
```

but :

```
bool([]) #False
```

from what i got values like [],0 .. are **False** what did i missed exactly and thanks!

Comment: Similarly `1.2 == 1` is false but `int(1.2) is 1`?

Comment: Pythons documentation of [boolean operations](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#booleans) says: "In the context of Boolean operations, and also when expressions are used by control flow statements, the following values are interpreted as false: `False`, `None`, numeric zero of all types, and empty strings and containers (including strings, tuples, lists, dictionaries, sets and frozensets)." To make it short: `==` is not a boolean operation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The operator `==` is very literal. If the 2 things you are comparing are not exactly the same (this includes types, like `"2" == 2` is `False`) then the result will always be `False`. So the boolean `False` is not literally the same thing as an empty list `[]` which is why `[] == False` is `False`.

An empty list is just treated as "False" when converted to a boolean, which you did with `bool([])`. So the output of `bool([])` is `False` which is literally the same as `False`. Thus `bool([]) == False` is `True`.

Comment: this one clears everything thanks !

Answer (score 1):

`[] != False`, but `bool([]) == bool(False)`.