# confusion while learning and understanding logic in Boolean

Tags: python-3.x, boolean, logic, boolean-logic

In python,
Why does (2 == True) #==> False but bool(2) #==> True ?
what logic differs between this two why does one provides False whereas the other True .

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is bool(\[\]) == False while \[\] == False is False and not True in python boolean logic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72997547/why-is-bool-false-while-false-is-false-and-not-true-in-python-boole)

Answer (score 2):

In the first case, `2 == True`, you are comparing the integer value 2 against the boolean value True. You are essentially asking whether those two are the same. In Python those are not the same, and so the python interpreter returns `False`.

In the second case, `bool(2)`, you cast the integer to a boolean. You are basically asking, if this was a boolean, what boolean value would it be? In Python, the bool method will always return True, unless:

- the provided object is empty, like `[], {}, ()`
- the provided object is `False`, like `3 == 4`
- the provided object is 0
- the provided object is `None`

Since the integer value 2 is none of the above, `bool(2)` will return `True`.

For more information about the `bool` method, check out [this link](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_booleans.asp).

Hope this helps!